# Google Universal Analytics event tracking for form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I've got a form with roughly 20 fields. There are both types of fields inputs and select. I need to send info about field usage to Google Analytics, but they allow to send only one request per event as far as I know. What I mean, is that one can't do something like

```
ga('send', 'event', [
    {'some.elaborate.event', 'some.elaborate.event'+$this.attr('alt'), 'username', $this.val()},
    {'some.elaborate.event', 'some.elaborate.event'+$this.attr('alt'), 'username', $this.val()},
    ...
]);
```

as far as I know.

Are there any solutions for such type of a problem?

Comment: What is the actual problem, though - too much typing with multiple "sends", too many http requests, ... ?

Comment: There is a limit/quota for requests with send. 2 requests per second.

Comment: how about using custom dimensions / metrics for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need one http request per event (that was the case even with the "old" Universal Analytics which allowed to push multiple events at once to ga - that still resulted in multiple calls to the tracking pixel).

IMO the best approach would be to track the form submissions as transactions with each submission as a single transaction and each field as a product. This will not save code or hits (each addItem call is a single interaction hit by the defintion of the google tos), but the resulting report will be much more userfriendly than the events report (e.g. you can click on the id for each form submission to break down by fields).

This will of not course not work well if you are already doing transaction tracking for actual products.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Only one question. I read a bit about it, but I don't see the use of transactions. Sure you can use them, but what for it is not clear. Usually you put something into transaction to ease the load or to have an ability to rollback. I sent transaction once and then all items(like in examples on developer.google), but in Google Analytics I don't see information about transaction, only products info.

Comment: There is a transaction report in the ecommerce section. With "normal" Ecommerce it's called "Transactions", with enhanced ecommerce it's sales performance (and with enhanced ecommerce the transaction id can be use to register refunds on a transaction).

Comment: Odd. I see data in Product Performance, but transaction tab is empty. Even though I do send one transaction per form submit. It has `ID` set. Or that won't suffice?